# i want to delete a row from table in javascript which stored in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

I want to delete a row from LocalStorage

This Method Works properly But it is removing the last row only, when i refresh it so instead of what i have clicked is not deleting

so please help me to get this issue resolve
in simple word i want to delete that row from localstorage, so when i reload the page so it will not be appear

### js file

```
 console.log('This is ES6 version of project 2');

const uid = function () {
    return Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
  };

class Book {

    constructor(name, author, type) {
        this.id = uid();
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class Display {
    add(book) {
        console.log('Adding to UI');
        let tableBody = document.getElementById('tableBody')
        let uiString = `<tr class="tableBody" id="tableBody" data-id="${book.id}">
                            <td id="search">${book.name}</td>
                            <td>${book.author}</td>
                            <td>${book.type}</td>
                            <td><input type="button" value="Delete Row" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="RemoveRow(this)"></td>
                        </tr>`;
        tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;

        // save the data to the browser's local storage -----
        const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
        // console.log(books);
        if (!books.some((oldBook) => oldBook.id === book.id)) books.push(book);
        localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(books));

    }
    

    clear() {
        let libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
        libraryForm.reset();
    }

    validate(book) {
        if (book.name.length < 2 || book.author.length < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    show (type, displayMessage) {
        let message = document.getElementById('message');
        let boldText;
        if (type === 'success'){
            boldText = 'Success';
        }
        else{
            boldText = 'Error!';
        }
        message.innerHTML = `<div class="alert alert-${type} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                <strong>${boldText}:</strong> ${displayMessage}
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>`
    
        setTimeout(function () {
            message.innerHTML = '';
        }, 5000);
    
    }
}

// Add submit event listener to libraryForm
let libraryForm = document.getElementById('libraryForm');
libraryForm.addEventListener('submit', libraryFormSubmit);

function libraryFormSubmit(e) {
    console.log('You have submitted library form')
    let name = document.getElementById('bookName').value;
    let author = document.getElementById('author').value;
    let type;
    let fiction = document.getElementById('fiction');
    let programming = document.getElementById('programming');
    let cooking = document.getElementById('cooking');
    if (fiction.checked) {
        type = fiction.value;
    }
    else if (programming.checked) {
        type = programming.value;
    }
    else if (cooking.checked) {
        type = cooking.value;
    }

    let book = new Book(name, author, type);
    console.log(book);

    let display = new Display();
    if (display.validate(book)) {
        display.add(book);
        display.clear();
        display.show('success', 'Your book has been successfully added')
    }
    else {
        // show error to the user
        display.show('danger', 'Sorry you cannot add this book.')
    }

    e.preventDefault();
}

(() => {
    const display = new Display();
    let books = localStorage.getItem("books");
    if (books) {
      books = JSON.parse(books);
      books.forEach((book) => display.add(book));
    }
    else
        localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify([])); 
})();

function RemoveRow(index) {
    let td1 = event.target.parentNode; 
    let tr1 = td1.parentNode; 
    tr1.parentNode.removeChild(tr1);
    const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("books"));
    // books.pop(books);
    const newBooks= books.filter(book=> book.id !== index).pop();
    localStorage.setItem("books", JSON.stringify(newBooks));
}
```

### html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Welcome to Juggu library</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.html"><b> Juggu library </b></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/about.html">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                          aria-expanded="false">
                          Websites
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="//allyouneed-notesapp.netlify.app/index.html">AllYouNeed Notes App</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="//textutilssystem.herokuapp.com">Text Utils</a>
                          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="//github.com/Mohammedvaraliya">github Profile</a>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex" role="search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" id="searchTxt" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="message">

        <!-- <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div> -->
          
    </div>

    <div class="container my-3" id="notes">
        <form id="libraryForm">
            <h1>Juggu library</h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="bookName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookName" placeholder="Book Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="Author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Author</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" placeholder="Author">
                </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset class="form-group row">
                <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 float-sm-left pt-0">Type</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="fiction" value="fiction" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="fiction">
                            Fiction
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="programming" value="programming">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="Programming">
                            Computer Programming
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="cooking" value="cooking">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="cooking">
                            Cooking
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn">Add Book</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="table">

            <h1>Your Books</h1>
            <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Author</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="tableBody" id="tableBody"> </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <!-- <script src="js/index.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/indexes6.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `book.id !== books` this looks wrong. shouldnt this maybe be `book.id !== index` ? (assuming that index already holds the ID. otherwise you would need to read it from the table row that you are removing)

Comment: No man, its not working

Comment: i tried this `book.id !== index` its not working

Comment: i want to delete from localstorange 
what u told is successfully removing the row but when i refresh the page, so it is appearing again

Comment: @MohammedVaraliya: Please either provide a runnable [mcve] or be more specific than "not working" (or, ideally, both).  When you debug this with your browser's debugging tools, stepping through the logic one line at a time, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the runtime values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: can i provide u the whole code

Comment: @MohammedVaraliya: You are encouraged to provide a runnable [mcve] as a working code snippet in the question.

Comment: is that enough code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `add` function, pass `book.id` to RemoveRow instead of `this` so that `RemoveRow` function gets the correct id of the book to remove

```js
let uiString = `<tr class="tableBody" id="tableBody" data-id="${book.id}">
                            <td id="search">${book.name}</td>
                            <td>${book.author}</td>
                            <td>${book.type}</td>
                            <td><input id="${book.id}" type="button" value="Delete Row" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="RemoveRow(this)"></td>
                        </tr>`;
```

I found a couple of more issues, in your RemoveRow function you don't have to use `pop`

```js
function RemoveRow(element) {
    const bookId = element.id;
    let td1 = document.getElementById(bookId).parentNode;
    let tr1 = td1.parentNode;
    tr1.parentNode.removeChild(tr1);
    const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')) || [];
    const newBooks = books.filter((book) => book.id !== bookId);
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(newBooks));
 }
```

And in your `add` function, when retrieving books for the first time books will be `null`, so initialize it to an empty array.

```js
....
tableBody.innerHTML += uiString;
// save the data to the browser's local storage -----
const books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')) || [];
....
```

Comment: can u please provide me with code am still stuck in that

Comment: @MohammedVaraliya, can you check now? I found two issues in the code and have added fixes to the answer. Basically when you're retrieving something from ````localStorage````, if the item is not present ````localStorage.get```` returns ````null````. So you have to give a fallback or check for it before doing actions like ````filter```` or ````some````

Comment: the RemoveRow function is not working 
basically is not taking any action, when i click to Delete Row , no response

Comment: its giving error `Uncaught ReferenceError: l5s3ci01qgfszwqn6wp is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:136:59)`

Comment: i have also change this `onclick="RemoveRow(this, ${book.id})"`

Comment: @MohammedVaraliya I have updated the RemoveRow function and add function, please check

Comment: Thanks You so much maan , thats What exactly i want 
It really help me from knowledge point of view and For my project also, and once again thank you so much